# What is the equivalent of App.cable for Rails 7?

Tags: developer-tools, actioncable, ruby-on-rails-7

I'm following along on DHH's Action Cable demo for Rails 5 [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n0WUjGkDFS0).

Using the browser's developer console, he gets a reference to the cable using `App.cable`. Attempting the same thing in Rails 7 throws

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined
```

I have poked around in the code generated by the rails action cable generator, and indeed there is nothing by that name. The configuration is quite different, though, between Rails 5 and Rails 7, and I'm struggling to find any way to grab a reference to the cable on the client side.

I have also tried to `Turbo.cable`, which returned `undefined`. I can see that a cable is connected (pic below). What could I use in console to interact with it?

[image: image of actioncable connected]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I figured out one way to do it. By default, if you use the rails generator to create a channel, e.g.

```
rails g channel room speak
```

You'll get a channel file named `room_channel.js` that looks like this:

```
import consumer from "channels/consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create("RoomChannel", {
  connected() {
    // Called when the subscription is ready for use on the server
  },

  disconnected() {
    // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
  },

  received(data) {
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
  },

  speak: function() {
    return this.perform('speak');
  }
});
```

Changing the second line to:

```
window.roomChannel = consumer.subscriptions.create("RoomChannel", {
```

makes `roomChannel` available in developer tools console. I can now type `roomChannel.speak()` on the client and see the received message on the server side.

Obviously this changes global state on `window`, but I think it's worth it for the ability to debug.